# Javascript Regexp insensitive

Tags: javascript, regex, salesforce

this is my problem :

I try to make a **specific regex** for a **Validation Pattern field in Salesforce**. The idea is to create Something to help people filling a textbox in a regular form.

Here are the **specifications** :

1. Authorized characters : `[a-z0-9/?:(),'.+ -]`
2. Words which are not accepted : `discount` and `www` also if another contain `discount` or `www` that must not be accepted like : `helldiscount` => not accepted
3. The whole regexp must be **insensitive**
4. Unauthorized specifications : `.xxx` (point with 3 letters next) and `.xx` (point with 2 letters next)

Here is the regexp **without** the specification **insensitive** and **specifications** :

```
^(?!discount|www)([a-zA-Z0-9/?:(),.'+ -]+)$
```

I worked on putting this regexp insensitive and trying to add the spécifications but my work actually does not work ; here is the work :

```
(?i)^(?!(?:discount|www)$)([a-z0-9/?:(),'.+ -]+)$
```

I miss Something and i can't understand what it is.

Help will be appreciated, thank you !

Comment: you forgot to escape /

Comment: @Rikin It's not necessary! It's inside the set!

Comment: regex101 gave me error despite it being inside the set. I guess it all depends on the library that you are trying to use which may have inclusive escaping or not.

Comment: @Rikin It depends on the delimiter being used. If `/`s the delimiter it needs to be escaped. On the far left of the regex in regex101 you can change the delimiter. https://regex101.com/r/vVx3DX/1 vs. https://regex101.com/r/vVx3DX/2

Answer (score 0):

You are testing if `discount` or `www` are not at the begining of the string, you have to test everywhere in the string:

```
^(?i)(?!.*discount|.*www)([a-zA-Z0-9/?:(),.'+ -]+)$
//      ^^         ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know salesforce, but in Javascript it would be easiest if you test if the following regex does **not** match:

```
(discount|www|[^a-z0-9/?:(),.'+ -])
```

Comment: Right here you match `discount` and `www` the goal is to match any other words or characters except those

Comment: yes, and I negated the character group. Therefore you only need to look if the regex does **not** match. In plain Javascript like
``if( ! texttovalidate.match( /(discount|www|[^a-z0-9/?:(),.'+ -])/i ) ) alert('Validation failed!');``